# django Field.choices read from a single file

Tags: python, django

I have a Field.choices in my model. lets say it is:

```
YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
    ('FR', 'Freshman'),
    ('SO', 'Sophomore'),
    ('JR', 'Junior'),
    ('SR', 'Senior'),
)


MEDIA_CHOICES = (
    ('Audio', (
            ('vinyl', 'Vinyl'),
            ('cd', 'CD'),
        )
    ),
    ('Video', (
            ('vhs', 'VHS Tape'),
            ('dvd', 'DVD'),
        )
    ),
    ('unknown', 'Unknown'),
)
```

I can access them using this method Model. YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES  but how can I save all of them into one single file and use them across my models? is it even possible? I mean I want to have a python file named `mychoise.py` and save all choices in there and then access them in this way

```
 year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=mychoise.YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
        default=FRESHMAN,
    )
```

Comment: you could do `from mychoise import YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES`

Comment: @HenryM thanks it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create the file `mychoise.py` in one of your app, add all your `choices` variables. Then to import them you just need to **import them** like the following **above all your models code**

```
from the_app.mychoise import *
form the_app.mychoice import YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES

choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES
```

or your can simply import the file

```
from the_app import mychoise

choices=mychoise.YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES
```

Comment: @thanks it worked. I know that this is not related to this question but I wondered if you can help me with it. is it possible to convert `YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES` them into a json object?

Answer (score 1):

You could import `YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES` from your module `mychoise`. Just remember having an `__init__.py` in the same directory as `mychoise.py`